# AngularJS Trying to find the total length of a filtered array that uses limitTo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

So I'm trying to get the total length of a filtered array in AngularJS after I've used LimitTo to keep the app from displaying more than a certain amount of elements at a time. The code is as follows:

```
<span>Results: {{filtered.length}}</span>
<li ng-repeat = "element in filtered = (array | filter:selectedTag | limitTo:load.number)">
```

I'm expecting about 150 total results but I'm keeping it limited to displaying 25 at a time. I want the Results to show the total length of the filtered array rather than just the limited version. Is there angular code to be able to get that without running the filter again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to avoid running the filter twice without writing some javascript to assign the result of the filter to a variable.

So, one solution would be to run the `selectedTag` filter in your controller whenever your array changes, store that locally and use it in your view.

Add this code to your controller:

```
.controler($scope, $filter) {
    // Existing code
    $scope.array = ...
    $scope.selectedTag = ...

    // New code
    $scope.filteredArray = [];

    $scope.$watchCollection('array', function (array) {
        $scope.filteredArray = $filter('filter')(array, $scope.selectedTag);
    });
}
```

And in your view:

```
<span>Results: {{filteredArray.length}}</span>
<li ng-repeat = "element in filteredArray | limitTo:load.number">
```

References
- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

Comment: This worked perfectly, but it required $scope.$watch('array', function (array) {
        $scope.filteredArray = $filter('filter')(array, $scope.selectedTag);
    }, true); in order to work

Comment: I believe `$watchCollection` will do the trick with less CPU cycles than deep watching - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-Scope-watch-vs-watchCollection-In-AngularJS.html. Edited the answer to user that instead.

Answer (score 9):

You're allowed to create a new variable *on-the-fly*, right inside the `ng-repeat` expression. This new variable can hold a reference to filtered results and it can be used outside of `ng-repeat`:

<kbd>[**PLUNKER DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tr7vKvWn73AzSR8KYgU0?p=preview)</kbd>

```html
<div>Total: {{array.length}}</div>
<div>Filtered: {{filtered.length}}</div>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="element in (filtered = (array | filter:selectedTag)) | limitTo:load.number">
      {{element}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

This way the filtering loop will run only once.

Comment: Nice solution. Much cleaner!